# AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'sample_from_datasets'

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have 3 datasets that I have assigned to 3 different TensorFlow datasets

```
tf_dataset_0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_0, y_train_0)
tf_dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_1, y_train_1)
tf_dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_2, y_train_2)
```

tf_dataset_2 is much larger than the two other datasets, but I want to sample them equally when I train the ML model and therefore I try to use the following method:

```
tf_dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets([tf_dataset_0 , tf_dataset_1 ,tf_dataset_2 ], weights=[0.33, 0.33, 0.33])
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'DatasetV2' has no attribute 'sample_from_datasets'
```

I use TensorFlow version 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Your error is probably due to some typo or missing parenthesis (maybe in `from_tensor_slices`), because this works for `TF 2.7.0` as expected:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# tf.__version__ 2.7.0

tf_dataset_0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 10)), tf.random.normal((50, 1))))
tf_dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 10)), tf.random.normal((50, 1))))
tf_dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((50, 10)), tf.random.normal((50, 1))))

tf_dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets([tf_dataset_0 , tf_dataset_1 ,tf_dataset_2 ], weights=[0.33, 0.33, 0.33])
for x, y in tf_dataset_train:
  print(x, y)
```

Comment: Yes, I think I did a mistake here I forgot to restart the environment after upgrading Tensorflow. However, I am using TPU and the 2.7.0 version does not support TPUs and therefore I can't use ```tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets``` together with TPUs

Comment: Yeah ok hmm that’s a completely different issue ;)

Comment: Oh and what makes you think TF 2.7.0 doesn’t support TPUs?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/supported-tpu-versions the TPU support only goes up to 2.6.0 at the moment

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu This seems to work with 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Try `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets` instead, as `tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets` is a later thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).